# Finding the Inverse of $f(x)=(x+6)/(x+1), x>-1, a=2$

Tags: calculus

So I'm having some trouble with this problem. Particularly getting the formula for the inverse function. I can plug in $x=2$ and then solve for the answer $(f^{-1}(2)=4)$, but I also want to learn how it is you're supposed to get the formula of the inverse.

$f^{-1}(x)= (6-x)/(x-1)$

Comment: Welcome! I'm unsure if you need the inverse of $f$, which is given by that ratio, or if you want an $f$ such that its inverse is that ratio (by ratio I mean $\frac{6-x}{x-1}$.

Comment: I need the inverse of (x+6)/(x+1). I have the answer, I just need to know how they got to it.

Comment: @WilliamH start more basic. How would you find the inverse of $f(x) = 2x + 1$?

Comment: I would change x and y, then solve for y.
finv(x)=(x-1)/2

Comment: Right, so have you tried doing that for $f(x) = \frac{x+6}{x+1}$?

Comment: Yes, but I must have messed up in my work. I'll redo it then.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get anything close to the answer based on how I'm trying to solve for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get  the inverse by solving the equation $\frac {x+6}{x+1}=y$ for $x$ in terms of $y$. Since $xy+y=x+6$ we get $x(y-1)=6-y$ so $x=\frac {6-y} {y-1}$. And the inverse function is given by $f^{-1}(y)= \frac {6-y} {y-1}$.

Comment: I don't think I understand how you get from 
xy+y=x+6 to x(y-1)=6-y.

Comment: @WilliamH Transfer $x$ on the right side to left side and use the fact that $xy-x=x(y-1)$. Then transfer $y$ on left side to the right side.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think to do that. Thank you, I see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y = \dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}
$,
then
$ax+b
=y(cx+d)
=cyx+dy
$
so
$ax-cyx = dy-b
$
or
$x(a-cy) = dy-b
$
or
$x
=\dfrac{dy-b}{a-cy}
$.

To check,

$\begin{array}\\
y 
&= \dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}\\
&= \dfrac{a\dfrac{dy-b}{a-cy}+b}{c\dfrac{dy-b}{a-cy}+d}\\
&= \dfrac{a(dy-b)+b(a-cy)}{c(dy-b)+(a-cy)d}\\
&= \dfrac{ady-ab+ab-bcy}{cdy-bc+ad-cdy}\\
&= \dfrac{(ad-bc)y}{ad-bc}\\
&= y
\qquad\text{if } ad-bc \ne 0&
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my approach:
$$y=\frac{x+6}{x+1}=\frac{(x+1)+5}{x+1}=1+\frac{5}{x+1}$$
So the inverse would have the equation
$$x=1+\frac{5}{y+1}$$ and you'd simply rearrange to obtain the inverse function. If you need any more help please ask :)